# cannot convert char* to int* in assignment c++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

C++ implicitly converts char to int (a larger data type than char) in an expression, which means the following runs without a compile time error:

```
char a = 'a';
int b = a;
cout << b << endl;
// output 
97
```

Why does the following then throw a compile time error:

```
char a = 'a';
char* str = &a;
int* ptr;
ptr = str;
```

Since pointers are of a fixed size (depending on 32/64 bit OS) irrespective of data type they are pointing to, please help me understand why this conversion is illegal.

Comment: Pointers still have strong type semantics, that's why this isn't allowed in c++.

Comment: You make an implicit assumption here that is nowhere guaranteed in the C++ standard itself. Nor is it likely to be guaranteed any time soon. Beyond that, pointer size is not the only consideration to keep in mind.

Comment: What happens when the compiler tries to write `4` bytes through the `int*` that is only pointing to `1` byte that the `char` is occupying?

Answer (score 3):

"*Since pointers are of a fixed size*" the problem is not the size of the pointer, but the pointed type, a *char* is not an *int*, so a *char ** is not an *int **

If you do after `*str = <value>` all is ok because you only change one byte, but `*ptr = <value>` will write into more than one byte with unexpected consequences etc

Comment: This is what i cannot understand. In implicit typecasting for data types, char is not an int even then, then why/how does implicit typecasting work?

Comment: _"char is not an int"_ Though you can implicitly convert a `char` to an `int` maybe that's the source of the OP's confusion.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta Again this is not because a char become an int without problem that it is the same for a pointer to a char

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is undefined behavior.

You start with a `char` and get a pointer to it. That's fine. For instance, the pointer could be `0x01`. Then you say, actually that pointer to 1 byte, let's make it to a pointer to 4 bytes (32bits assumption for an `int`).

Obviously, that cannot work. Where are the other 3 bytes coming from?

Then, let's say that it does work. You get alignment issues, because the int should be aligned on 4bytes boundaries, and your pointer is not.

Hence lots and lots of issues what you want to do:

- access to inexistent memory
- bad memory access (alignement).

This cannot work.

When you assign a char to an int, you create a new variable, a new place with 4 bytes that can receive your data. Here, you don't create a new variable that can hold that data.

Answer (score 1):

You had stated:

> C++ implicitly typecasts char to int (a larger data type than char) in an expression, which means the following runs without a compile time error:
>
> ```
> char a = 'a';
> int b = a;
> cout << b << endl;
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 97
> ```

Then you asked:

> Why does the following then throw a compile time error:
>
> ```
> char a = 'a';
> char* str = &a;
> int* ptr;
> ptr = str;
> ```

---

In your first example, you declare a `char` variable named `a` and assign it the character `'a'`. Then you declare an `int` variable named `b` and assign it the value of `a`. Then you call `cout` on `b`. This gives a value of `97` which is expected.

What is happening here is the compiler will implicitly cast the value of the char `a` to an integer. The reason you are seeing the value `97` is because this is the assigned `ASCII` code for the lower case `a`. The variable sizes here don't matter.

---

In your second example where you begin to ask about your compiler error is as follows:

You declare the same `char` variable as above and assign it the same character value `a`.
This time you create a `pointer` to a `char` and name it `str` and assign it to the address of `a`. `str` now points to `a`. Next you created a `pointer` to an `int` named `ptr`, then you try to assign `str` to `ptr`. Yes all pointers have the same size in memory, but what you are failing to understand here, is how pointer addressing works. Since you are not using `new` & `delete` respectively these pointers are on the stack. So on my machine I have ran this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char* str = &a;
    std::cout << &str << '\n'; // print str's address
    int* ptr; // don't assign ptr to anything...
    std::cout << &ptr << '\n'; // print ptr's address
}
```

On my machine the output is:

```
003BFC34  // this is the stack address of str
003BFC28  // this is the stack address of ptr
```

---

Yes both pointers themselves typically take up 4 bytes of memory on a 32bit machine. However, `str` is pointing to a char type of 1 byte, and `ptr` is pointing to a int type of 4 bytes on a 32bit machine.

So when you try to assign one pointer to another; this will only work when the pointer types are of the same type! Otherwise, you will either have a compiler error in your case or `UB`.

Your assumption in the first case is that the `char` became an `int` and that is not the case. What happens in your first case is it is taking the value that is represented by `1 byte` and implicitly converts it to an integer type that takes `4 bytes` and the integer representation of the lowercase `a` is the `ASCII` value of `97`.

---

Therefore your 2nd case will not compile:

```
int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char* str = &a;
    int* ptr = str; // fails to compile.
    return 0;
}
```

However, there is a way to convert pointers from one type to another

```
int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char* str = &a;
    int* ptr = (int*)(str); // C Style Cast - Will Compile!
    int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>( str ); // This will compile!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if there is another char before, or a short, then this will crash during execution if you access `ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

When you  assign int value to char variable and vice versa the compiler do the casting implictly. 
But if you assign pointer of type int to address of char variable, it's illegal, because it's int pointer it should point to int variable.
The other direction is the same, char pointer should point to char integer. 
The reason is because in memory char represented in one byte while int represented with four bytes. 
It's important for memory allocating and freeing.